# Need to display none or not generate chart marks

Tags: javascript, c3.js

This CSS is working for remove marks...

```
#mychart .c3-circles-avg2017,
#mychart .c3-circles-avg2018 {
   display: none;
}
```

is **a ugly way to do it**, because all configs and chart definitions are at Javascrpt. I need to do **by Javascript**, ideal is to use C3 or D3...  I try D3 and **it is not working**:

```
d3.selectAll('#mychart .c3-circles-avg2017').style("display","none");
d3.selectAll('#mychart .c3-circles-avg2018').style("display","none");
```

how to obtain same CSS effect by Javascript?  (or say to C3 not put marks).

---

(edit after @thatOneGuy comment)

### oops, sorry, my D3 command is working... So it is only a C3 question

https://jsfiddle.net/jo1h0dyb/

Comment: Works here http://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/os6x43h1/1/ d3.selectAll('#body .test').style('display', "none"). a working example would be great

Comment: Thanks @thatOneGuy you're right (!), I edited. We can reduce the scope of the question to "C3 solution please", D3 is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for the circles in a line graph, and you want to do it in the config, point.r is what needs set. It's not clear from the reference but it can take a function that has a datapoint {id, index, value, x} as an argument as well as a fixed value.

https://c3js.org/reference.html#point-r

Try this in your case:

```
point: {
  r: function (d) { return (d.id === "avg2017" || d.id === "avg2018") ? 0 : 5 }
}
```

Comment: thanks! There are a good C3 guide that say things like that? *"Hide marks with point.r=0"*...

Comment: Just the c3 reference page I linked to, and a lot of the newer/updated things aren't covered. Some of the stuff I just find by poking about the c3 source code. The github site is also a good resource - https://github.com/c3js/c3