# How to access the current value of point.r?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56977422/287948) is returning  literal constant (`return 5`), but on my real life chart it is so big, the internal value is other... How to access it?

PS: even something  as `chart.internal.config.point_r` is wrong because I need the "current value" not the original config, and I not have `chart` variable, need a kind of `this.etc.point_r`  value to be returned.

Example:

```
point: {
  r: d=> (String(d.id) === "avg")? 0: thisCurrentMysterious.point_r
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the default value for point r you're after it's 2.5

You can access this (and more) through this method (undocumented again), basically c3 uses these values when you don't supply one in your config -->

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.getDefaultConfig()
```

so `c3.chart.internal.fn.getDefaultConfig().point_r` returns 2.5

So I reckon

```
point: {
  r: d=> (String(d.id) === "avg")? 0: c3.chart.internal.fn.getDefaultConfig().point_r
}
```

is what you want?

Comment: Hum... Make sense,  but as I expressed, I need the *"current value"*, that is any: 1. a default; 2. the user-defined;  3. the calculated (because if you change chart's width   and height it changes the point_r value). So I need to test, but `getDefaultConfig()`  not seems the solution.

Comment: Do you mean a way to access the point.r function for a particular chart? For that you will need the chart variable to access it. Or do you mean the actual drawn radius of the points? This could be done by accessing the dom and getting the r attribute of the drawn circle elements. Perhaps if you made a little code example of what you want to do it would be clearer to me?

Comment: The "access the point.r function for a particular chart" in your words, but by a king of *this* variable, the fragment is into the chart.  This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qwpvLj6r/) is a good example, and show that I am wrong about circle radius  changing with chart size (**was a visual illusion** on my real life C3 use). So seems my item 3 (calculed) not exist. The `c3.chart.internal.fn.getDefaultConfig().point_r` is the item 1 (solved!), and item 2 is in context conflict because `point: etc` is the user definition.  So closing, all is solved here.